# Разная реакция сервера на нажатие кнопки на телефоне и компьютере CORS policy

Tags: javascript, python, html, fastapi

Сейчас с помощью Javascript я отправляю пост запрос к апи на сервере. На компьютере все работает адекватно, однако попытался повторить то же самое действие с мобильного устройства и столкнулся со следующей ошибкой:

> Access to fetch at 'http://my-site:8000/receiver' from origin
> 'http://www.my-site:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

В то же время на пк на этой же версии сайта все работает без ошибок. Обработчик нажатия на кнопку:

```
add_button.onclick = async function () {
    let result = { "text": text_field.value, "stat": "new" }
    await fetch("http://my-site:8000/receiver",
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(result)
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            number = data;
            console.log(number)
        });
}
```

Comment: А у вас точно открыт один и тот же сайт? Может на компьютере у вас открыт `http://my-site:8000`,  а на телефоне `http://www.my-site:8000`?

Comment: Да, точно открыт один и тот же :)

Comment: Однако очень интересно, что если открыть на пк сайт с www то ошибка та же. Получается chrome на телефоне скрывает от меня часть url...

Comment: `www.` хром уже давно скрывает

Comment: Но проще всего в запросе убрать часть `http://my-site:8000` и вообще не думать про CORS

Comment: Получается просто относительно через /receiver ?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в запросе от адреса с url содержащим "www." к url без "www."

Помог совет Alexey Ten:

> проще всего в запросе убрать часть http://my-site:8000 и вообще не
> думать про CORS.

Соответственно избавляемся от левой части url полностью и оставляем только "/receiver" и все работает.